# How to create a stored proceedure in mysql?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, syntax-error

Just trying to make a procedure that copies one table into a new one but keep getting all sorts of errors..

eg:
SQL Error [1064] [42000]: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE spClean_T()
BEGIN
CREATE TABLE staging_table AS ' at line 2

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE spClean_T()
BEGIN
    CREATE TABLE staging_table AS SELECT * FROM raw_api_data
END$$

DELIMITER ;`
```

thanks

Comment: CREATE TABLE statement must be finalized with `;`. Also you may remove BEGIN-END - it is excess in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to end all commands with a semicolon or else mysql will search for more  code

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE spClean_T()
BEGIN
    CREATE TABLE staging_table AS SELECT * FROM raw_api_data;
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

But if you don't have more commands

Make a simple without DELIMITER

```
CREATE PROCEDURE spClean_T()
CREATE TABLE staging_table AS SELECT * FROM raw_api_data;
```